# Understanding the Biclust class in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm new in R Language, but I'm using the biclust package for Bicluster Analysis. After to search information in web, I could run some biclustering algorithms but I could not access to the resulting information.

For Example, after run

```
> library("biclust") 
> data(BicatYeast)
> x<-discretize(BicatYeast)                                                    
> Xmotif <- biclust(x, method=BCXmotifs(), number=50, alpha=0.5, nd=20, ns=20, sd=5)
```

The variable *Xmotif* is an object of class Biclust that contains the bicluster resulted. However, when I print in console the variable *Xmotif* R show me only a short information about the 5 firts biclusers like follow:

```
> Xmotif
An objects of class Biclust

call:
       biclust(x, method=BCXmotifs(), number=50, alpha=0.5, nd=20, ns=20, sd=5)

Number of Clusters found: 50
First  5  Cluster sizes:
                   BC 1 BC 2 BC 3 BC 4 BC 5
Number of Rows:       3    4    3    5    3
Number of Columns:   47   44   41   38   46
```

Then, How can I get all information about the 50 biclusters found?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the internal `writeBiclusterResults()` function in the documentation?

Comment: What would your ideal result look like?

Comment: Well, I'm not using *writeBiclusterResults()* because the tutorials always show it this way, but, I'm going to search it. I like to handle the information about the biclustering algorithm result, this mean, a list of all the biclusters (for the example the 50 biclusters) and, for each bicluster show theirs objects and fectures (also referenced by genes and conditions respectively).

Comment: That looks exactly like the result saved out of writeBiclusterResults().

Comment: Thank polka, this is what I want. Also, with bicluster(BicatYeast,Xmotif). Thank you very mush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the built in function `writeBiclusterResults()`.

```
library("biclust") 
data(BicatYeast)
x<-discretize(BicatYeast)                                                    
Xmotif <- biclust(x, method=BCXmotifs(), number=50, alpha=0.5, nd=20, ns=20, sd=5)  

writeBiclusterResults("results.txt", Xmotif,"CC with delta 1.5", dimnames(BicatYeast)[1][[1]], dimnames(BicatYeast)[2][[1]])
```

Comment: polka, why do you use *discretize* before to apply the algorithm?

Comment: From the docs... Some biclusteralgorithms need a discrete matrix to perform well. This function delivers a discrete matrix with either a given number of levels of equally spaced intervals from minimum to maximum, or levels of same size using the quantiles.